# How to check if finished pressing sprite in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: ios, touch

I have a couple of buttons and a joystick on my screen and I want to check if one of those is no longer being pressed, I of course can check if the finger is inside the button to check which one was let go, but how can I know if the finger is no longer in the button? Like assigning the touch that triggered each button and then checking if that is the one that was let go of. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nevermind I saw touches have a unique ID and used that, but thanks.